# Not asking password in my gitlab Repository

Tags: gitlab

```
PS E:\Angular> git clone https://gitlab.com/souravgolui/MatDash.git <br>
Cloning into 'MatDash'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied<br>
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/souravgolui/MatDash.git/'
```

This error will show in command prompt. please help.
I entered wrong password , but not asking password 2nd time.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830318/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If password not asking(prompt popup), and saying authentication failed then follow below steps:

1. click on start
2. Type : Credential Manager
3. See the Windows (Manager shortcut or Credential Manager shortcut) and double-click it to open the application
4. Once the app is open, click on the ("Windows Credentials" or "Generic Credentials") tab where git:https://...
5. select edit and modify your update pwd then save it.***

Now enjoy your work :)

Comment: many many thanks.. While nothing worked, your answer saved my day.

Comment: It worked, but I had troubles finding credentials manager in my localized version of windows. If someone looks for it, it's about this one https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager

Answer (score 5):

You need to store your password once again :

```
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Then try to push again

If you need more informations about this command, check the git's manual :

```
git help credentials
```

Good luck

Comment: In my case I needed to add the --global flag