# VSCode remote: Repository not found, fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Without me changing anything whatsoever, I can't now push any changes into my repository.

By doing `git push`, I receive the following error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/...';
```

I have seen multiple topics about the same subject like:

- [Git push results in "Authentication Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed)
- [Getting "fatal: Authentication failed" -error when sending git commands in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830318/getting-fatal-authentication-failed-error-when-sending-git-commands-in-windo)
- [Git log out user from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238037/git-log-out-user-from-command-line)

And none of the solutions worked:

1. I went to "Windows Credentials" and deleted the entry vscode:github
2. I ran the command `git config --global --unset credential.helper` and nothing popup
3. I ran the command `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` and didn't find any github entry related
4. Installed Git Credential Manager for Windows, and ran the command `git credential-manager clear`
5. Executed CMD as administrator and ran the command in the point 2.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue with VS Code version 1.62.2.
I downgraded to version 1.62.1 and it works again.

Comment: It's still an issue in 1.62.3