# git clone: Authentication failed for <URL>

Tags: windows, git, tfs, credentials

Trying to access private corporate tfs.
They gave me access by giving appropriate rights to windows user (domain\login).

I'm fine with accessing web interface of tfs, browse repository and stuff.

But when I try to run

```
 git clone https://tfs.somehostname.com/tfs/somefolder/_git/therepository
```

It fails with

```
Cloning into 'therepository'...

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://tfs.somehostname.com/tfs/somefolder/_git/therepository/'
```

Tried with home pc without corporate network stuff - same error.

Tried in PowerShell, Git Bash, Clone via VisualStudio - same error.

SSH is closed (gave request timeout).

Web & Git both ask for credentials once (tried deleting in Credentials Manager - asks again, after submitting web is fine, git fails)

Corporate helper tried to help, but all he gave is tfs logs.
He says, my username doesn't come with requests (tracked by syncing my attempts timestamps with logs).

```
2018-07-19 07:04:00 SOMEIP GET /tfs/SOMEFOLDER/_git/REPOSITORY/info/refs service=git-upload-pack 443 - ANOTHERIP git/2.12.2+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.3.9600.0;+Win32NT+x64)+CLR/4.0.30319+VS15/15.0.0 - 401 2 5 62
2018-07-19 07:23:00 SOMEIP GET /tfs/SOMEFOLDER/_git/REPOSITORY/info/refs service=git-upload-pack 443 - ANOTHERIP git/2.18.0.windows.1 - 401 2 5 62
2018-07-19 07:23:00 SOMEIP GET /tfs/SOMEFOLDER/_git/REPOSITORY/info/refs service=git-upload-pack 443 - ANOTHERIP git/2.18.0.windows.1 - 401 1 3221225581 187
```

while others include it

```
2018-07-19 05:44:27 SOMEIP GET /tfs/SOMEFOLDER/_git/REPOSITORY/info/refs service=git-upload-pack 443 DOMAIN\LOGIN ANOTHERIP git/2.12.2+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.1.7601+Service+Pack+1;+Win32NT+x64)+CLR/4.0.30319+VS15/15.0.0 - 200 0 0 265
```

Comment: Did you tell `git` who you are by setting your email/password? Check that by looking up `git config --list` and provide the output with your question. You probably have to do `git config --global user.email YourEmail@Company.com`

Comment: Email is present, no password. Here is full output: https://pastebin.com/WKWPqejk i should add that im logged as different user from allowed one and even domain of allowed user is unavailable from this machine

Comment: Try to put the username/password on the git clone: `git clone https://username:password@https://tfs.somehostname.com/tfs/somefolder/_git/therepository/`

Comment: Tried `https://domain%5Cusername@tfs.somehostname.com/tfs/somefolder/_git/therepository/` - didnt work. Good idea tho.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830318/getting-fatal-authentication-failed-error-when-sending-git-commands-in-windo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit was russian account password.

Accidentally set up it (wrong keyboard layout).
Everything was working, so didnt bother changing it.

Out of despair changed it now and it worked.

If someone looked up this thread and its not a solution for you - check out comments under the question and steps i described in question, they might be useful to you.

Comment: What is a *russian account password*?

Comment: a password written using russian layout keyboard...apparently

Comment: @zwcloud  A password consisting of cyrillic letters. For example "привет" or "Новый_пароль".

Answer (score 161):

I faced same error on my development machine. I was trying to clone a repository. My machine had a newly installed Windows Server operating system. I was using Git bash as my Git client. When I ran Git's command to clone a repository it was *not* prompting me for user id and password which will be used for authentication. It was a new PC so no credentials were cached by Windows credential manager.

As a last resort, I manually added my credentials in credentials manager following below steps:

1. Press <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open **Run** prompt.
2. Type **Control** and press <kbd>OK</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>User Accounts</kbd> on **Control Panel** window.
4. Click <kbd>Credential Manager</kbd> on **User Accounts** window.
5. Click <kbd>Windows Credentials</kbd> on **Credential Manager** window.

Now, click <kbd>Add a Windows credential</kbd> in **Windows Credentials** section (refer yellow highlighting in screenshot below):

[image]

Now, enter the details as shown in the form below and click <kbd>OK</kbd>:

[image]

I had put the details as below:

```
Internet or network address: <gitRepoServerNameOrIPAddress>
User Name: <DomainName\MyUserName>
Password: <MyPassword>
```

Next time when you run any Git command targeting a repository set up on above address, this manually cached credential will be used.

**Note**:

1. Close and relaunch any open Git bash, Powershell or command shell for the credential caching to take effect.
2. From now on, whenever your domain account password changes then you'll have to update it on this screen as well. In corporate environment this happens regularly due to password rotation policy.

**Update(12-Jun-2022)**: If adding a Windows credentials doesn't work for you then you can try <kbd>Add a generic credential</kbd> instead (refer screenshot below). Please note that while adding a generic credentials, Internet or network address of your TFS server is of the format:

```
git:https://YourTfsServerAddress
```

[image]

Comment: this locked my account a couple of times when i was forced to change the pw, the creds are not updated, mentioning this just for awareness.

Comment: I had to add address "git:" in the beginning of the address  as ```git:https://www.YourWebsiteAddress.com```

Comment: This worked for me, even when using WebStorm as my IDE

Comment: This is the perfect solution!! Thanks

Comment: To clarify, the first box should be a host name or IP address like MyServer or www.YourServer.com or 123.1.1.5

Comment: I had to add to the ```generic credential``` section and add the url as @AZ pointed out. (i.e. do ```git:https://etc.com```)  then simply adding my username and passowrd .

Comment: nice solution!!! for Windows 10, the add functionality start with link "Add  a generic credential" under tab "Windows credential"

Comment: I had this issue after changing my primary email on my git azure account, changing it back fixed the issue.

Comment: and for ubuntu? @RBT

Answer (score 66):

Go to > `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager` > `Manage Windows Credentials`
and remove all generic credentials involving **Git**. (This way you're resetting all the credentials)

After this, when you clone, you'll be **newly** and **securely** asked your Git username and password instead of Authentication error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works like magic! This is a MUST after password change for your credentials...

Comment: Password reset was the problem... solution spot on....

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I needed to do this after a password reset.

Comment: In German it's "Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung" for Credential Manager.

Comment: After wrongly giving the password for one of my friend, used the same steps to resolve. Quick solution ...

Comment: I really wish the git command line prompted for a new password. VSCode does.

Answer (score 55):

Adding `username` and `password` has worked for me: For e.g.

```
https://myUserName:myPassWord@myGitRepositoryAddress/myAuthentificationName/myRepository.git
```

Comment: That looks like a security risk try just passing your username with no password on the URL instead.

Comment: Can confirm, only passing username will indeed ask for password and work correctly.

Answer (score 36):

For cloning a private repository simply putting the `password` and `username` will not be enough as the terminal will not tell but you will have to copy the `personal_access_token` using the github account and put it in the place of your password.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

Further you can easily access your token through the steps given below: -
[image: Go to Settings]
[image: Developer Setting]
[image: Personal_acess_token]
Now check the repo column and now click on `Generate token`
[image: Generate token]
[image: Congratulations!!]
Now copy and it and paste it when the terminal asks for password.

`NOTE: - Treat your tokens like passwords and keep them secret`

Comment: Well then. Good thing that's well documented. /s

Comment: While this worked, surely one can't keep doing this every 30 days???

Comment: Thanks for commenting @user997112 but there is also an option to customize the duration for which you want the token to be generated. I think the almost duration for which you can generate the token is around 1 year.

Answer (score 6):

If credentials are not asked then simplest solution is to clone using credentials.
[image]

Option B would be suitable in case password includes any special character which URL's treat in odd manner. This option asks password.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is facing this issue with Azure DevOps, there the fix is very easy, just adding Git credentials to a repository.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager and select Generic Credentials.
2. Remove all the credential with your company domain name.
3. Git clone repository from git bash terminal once again and it will ask for password and username. Insert it again and you are all set!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with my windows 10 machine, I tried many solutions but nor worked until I installed the latest git version. https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Answer (score 2):

I had also faced the same situation. After checking this post, found the solution and it works perfectly.

### Windows PC::

1. Open -> Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager
2. Open -> Windows Credentials
3. Just update the git password for your URL.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest, editing/removing credentials in the `Manage Windows Credentials` work and does the job. However, you need to do this each time when the password changes or credentials do not work for some work. Using `ssh key` has been extremely useful for me where I don't have to bother about these again once I'm done creating a `ssh-key` and adding them on the server repository (github/bitbucket/gitlab).

**Generating a new ssh-key**

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Paste the text below, substituting in your repo's email address.
   `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
3. When you're prompted to "Enter a file in which to save the key," press Enter. This accepts the default file location.
4. Then you'll be asked to type a secure passphrase. You can type a passphrase, hit enter and type the passphrase again.

Or, Hit enter twice for empty passphrase.

5. Copy this on the clipboard:

   clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

And then add this key into your repo's profile. For e.g, on *github->setting->SSH keys ->  paste the key that you coppied ad hit add*

Ref: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key

You're done once and for all!

Answer (score 1):

After trying almost everything on this thread and others, continuing to Google, the only thing that worked for me, in the end, was to start Visual Studio as my AD user via command line:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE
runas /netonly /user:<comp\name.surname> devenv.exe
```

Original issue:
[1]: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/304224/git-failed-with-a-fatal-errorauthentication-failed.html

My situation is I'm on a personal machine connecting to a company's internal/local devops server (not cloud-based) that uses AD authorization. I had no issue with TFS, but with git could not get the clone to work (Git failed with a fatal error. Authentication failed for [url]) until I did that.

Answer (score 1):

For the new comers,

Upvoted answers are not the answers anymore since,

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13,
> 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
> remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information.

And no need to repeat the access token replies, go and follow them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when Cloning the repository via Bash/VS Code with "fatal:Authentication failed". I used SSH Key authentication instead to connect my repository following the article: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page][1] 
I didn't get any errors after with any bash commands!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than escape my password I left it out and was prompted for it, but only when I included the domain name before my username:

```
git clone https://some-dom-name\firstname.lastname@tfs.somedomain.com/tfs/...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was some old username and password was stored in cache.

So I removed it by going to sourceTree and delete the existing account.

Now for the new clone then it will ask you for the password for the repo.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer here. Open git bash go to path `git/mingw64/libexec/git-core` and run the following command:

```
./git-credential-manager clear
```

Next time you execute a clone, a dialog will open and which credential manager do you want. I selected `wincred` (don't know if it is the best option). Checked the box so it won't ask again. Another similar dialog will open again.

By the way, it always better to authenticate using your ssh keys. Don't checkout using https. If you have to type your password every time you interact with the server, you will do it less, and merge your code less often. More conflicts will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Despite having login failed through Sorucetree and gitbash by entering credentails in the prompt window, GitHub Desktop application worked with no hassle

[GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this issue. The easiest way is to select Clone in Visual Studio. Visual Studio then prompts for your credentials. After you enter your credentials, you set the path. Then your repository is cloned.

Answer (score 0):

1- Clean all the credentials from windows as stated in the answers above
2- Make sure you have the latest git, if your git is not updated to the latest version you will get this error too.

3- once you completed above steps. just simply clone and it will ask for credentials and will work

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem today.
Tried a few answers from here, but what finally worked for me was to clone directly from the IDE, in my case - visual studio.

The IDE prompted for username and password and that was the end of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with cloning. It was showing authentication failed without even asking for credentials because it wasn't able to reach the link requested.

To solve it I did that:
get link for cloning -> `git bash here` in desired directory -> `git config --system -e` -> delete credentials from file (4/5 rows) -> save -> `git config --global -e` -> delete credentials (2/3 rows) -> save -> `git clone <link>` -> DONE

Answer (score 0):

If GitHub has **two-factor authentication** enabled, utilize the `Personal Access Token` in place of the user password.

Personal Access Token generated through the following steps.

1. Click the User Image Button in the top right corner
2. Click `Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token > Tokens (Classic) > Generate New Token > Generate New Token(Classic).`
3. Enter a `Note` and set an `Expiration`.
4. Click "Generate Token" to receive an access token (e.g.,
   `ghp_saNd4fqQtaorXXXXX3dFeOTVeSyjf2wM0BS`).
5. Clone the project successfully using this command: `git clone https://github.com/user_name/project_name` with the provided token instead of a password.

Retrieve details by visiting the following URL - [docs.github.com](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#basic-authentication)

Answer (score -1):

Go to:

> Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials -> Generic Credentials >> Remove old credentials which were saved for the specific url

Then when you freshly clone the repository it will prompt for credentials.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Gitlab,  for some reason,  git clone with http just does not work. Git clone with ssh is the only option.

```
git clone git@gitlab.example.com:demo.git
```