# cannot clone private repository with git

Tags: git, github, clone

I set up a private test repository, and tried to clone as follows:

```
git clone https://aryehw@github.com/aryehw/testPrivate  
Cloning into 'testPrivate'...  
Password for 'https://aryehw@github.com':   
remote: Invalid username or password.  
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/aryehw/testPrivate/'
```

I found the following discussion, and tried some of the proposed solutions. No joy.
[git clone: Authentication failed for <URL>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424051/git-clone-authentication-failed-for-url)

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, POP-OS

This is the output of git version:

amw@pop-os:~/git$ git version
git version 2.25.1

Comment: https://github.com/aryehweiss/testPublic/ gives me 404, is that intended? :) welcome to SO

Comment: Thank you. It should be aryehw, not aryehweiss. Now it works for the public repository. However, I still cannot clone a private repository, after entering the password.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62633290/edit) your post to include the change

Comment: Please edit in the right example, as it now sounds like you're having problems with a private repository, and since the one in the question is named "testPublic" I assume that isn't it. Also, out of curiosity, what does `git version` output?

Comment: Thank you. The question is now updated.