# Git authentication Failed when cloning into TFS private Repo

Tags: node.js, git, azure-devops, tfs

I am using TFS for my repos and all are private . moreover i have also added hostFiles into my computerOS because that is for extra security and also set my username and password in credential manager . But still no luck and whenever i use  `git clone` then the following error happens

```
fatal: Authentication failed for
```

kindly Help

I have tried using credential managers and have rechecked my credentails multiple times . Reinstalled Git but am unable to understand what is causing the issue

Comment: You can try the suggestions in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424051/git-clone-authentication-failed-for-url) and check if it works.

Comment: trying but not sure what am doing wrong its been 2 days since am stuck at this .

Comment: You should not have to setup a hosts file. Can you turn on tracing in git and the gcm to see what the error is? What version of TFS/Azure DevOps? Is your laptop domain joined?

Comment: https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/environment.md#gcm_trace

Comment: What version of git? What version of git credential manager? Is git configured to use OpenSSL or Windows Secure Channel (SChannel)?

Comment: git version 2.42.0

Comment: Moreover am my machine was using a vpn before and now we configured to work with another VPN .  my machine is using one password for all the things like for window login , mail etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well i have found a solution after spending much hours on this . i just reinstalled GIT and then upon installation i skipped the part for installing credential manager and i selected None. After that when i clone the Repo the Git asked for Username ad password and now everything is working Fine

Comment: It's great to know you can resolve the issue and thanks for sharing your solution. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept the answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Comment: yes sure . as i was stuck for two days and will definitely do it