# Azure Visual Studio 2019 failed to push to Azure DevOps Git

Tags: azure-devops, ssl-certificate, repository, azure-synapse, azure-sql-server

**Background**

- I have an **Azure Synapse SQL server** which have some tables and stored procedures. **Visual Studio 2019 (VS2019)** is connected to the SQL server using Active Directory Interactive Authentication with use name being a *Service Account Email*.
- I have built a **Azure DevOps Demo**, with following setups (Organization, Project, Git Repository).
- I have added the *Service Account Email* to the Azure DevOps project and repository level, with contributor access.
- I am trying to synchronize the stored procedures with my Azure DevOps Repository.
- I am able to use **VS2019** > **Team Explorer** > **Manage Connections**, and set the *Service Account Email* as the "hosted repositories for", and see my Repositories appear in the list.

**Problem**

1. It turned out that when I try to push **Git Changes**, by **Team Explorer** > **New Repository** > **Existing remote**, where I entered the full URL of my repository *https//dev.azure.com/%Organization%/%Project%/_git/%Repository%*, following error turned up: ***Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access 'above URL': SSL certificate problem, unable to get local issuer certificate***. How can I resolve this error?
2. How to push all of my existing stored procedures to my Repository?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, requesting you to go through the link. Hope this will resolve the issue:

[Authentication failed for https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834117/authentication-failed-for-https-xxx-visualstudio-com-defaultcollection-git-pr)